# Read-only thread safety

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

What is mean term "Read-only thread safety"  Can anyone post some code example?

Answer (score 2):

The example could be some STL container, initialized like this

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(1);
vec.push_back(2);
```

If **not modified**, this `vec` can be used by several threads accessing its fields. It's **safe**, while the members of `vec` are not changed nor the memory it occupies.

```
int n = vec.at(0);// good. many threads can do this
// many threads could do this too
for( std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it )
{
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

It's **not safe** though if other thread does some writing/modification over `vec` while someone is reading it.

```
vec.push_back(3); // bad: vec could get expanded and the data relocated
vec[ 0 ] = 5; // bad: someone could read invalid data
```

Comment: Good answer. It should be noted that it is particularly *safe* to iterate in parallel over the vector - if the vector had only one iteration pointer in it, it wouldn't be read-only thread-safe to do above loop.